# gsb projection file for qgis under MAC OSX

Tags: qgis, mac, osx

I'm trying to create a new projection inside wgis. The projection includes a gsb file. With the Windows OS is easy to implemnet that: you just need to place the gsb file inside the C:\Programs\Qgis[Qgis ver]\share\proj and in Linux OS is easy as well because the gsb file goes to /usr/share/proj.

Where to put gsb files within Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

After some attempts I've found a some sort of solution. As I can understand there's no way to find a default repository for gsb file as for Windows or Linux so you need to define the gsb full path inside the target-CRS string. E.g if the ROME40.gsb is inside /Users/dzuliani/
format the +nadgrids as in the following string

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +k=1.000000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +nadgrids=/Users/dzuliani/ROME40.gsb +wktext
```